# Replace null varchar fields with empty string for whole db

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm rebuilding a legacy program for a client ... the database is relatively well designed the only thing I don't care for is all the null varchar values ... (personally don't care for handing this in my client code ... )

I'm trying to replace all null varchar columns with empty strings ... normally I would do this in my import script but I don't need to modify the schema so I'm not going to do an import script ...

wondering if any of you slick SQL guys /girls know a way to foreach (varchar column in db) replace null with '' kinda thing?

I know there must be a way ... P.S. MSSQL 2008r2 DB

Comment: NULL means "missing or not applicable." what does empty-string mean, and why is that better?

Comment: Also, if any of the varchar values are FK's you will have to add 'empty string' to the referenced table. brrrrr

Comment: @bumble_bee, this is a bad idea, I suggest solving it with coalesce in the select statements that do the output.

Comment: @n8wrl: +1 Your second comment gives the best reason **not to** do this plan. I would add that it would break any query with `IS NULL`, `IS NOT NULL` conditions in these varchar columns. And possibly many `LEFT JOIN` queries.

Comment: I appreciate the possible issues however they are not applicable in this situation ... There is no reason why a name field need to be null rather then an empty string though ... I knew this was gonna get heated lol ...

Comment: Well, if you know what you are doing, then you can use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` Views to get all tables and varchar field names: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx

Comment: You can probably modify this script (that searches over all fields and tables) to do the update: http://blogs.thesitedoctor.co.uk/tim/2010/02/19/Search+Every+Table+And+Field+In+A+SQL+Server+Database+Updated.aspx

Comment: @n8wrl there are no queries, no source !!! rewriting cobalt application lol ... @ypercube if you post that as an answer I will mark it as such that is precisley what I am attempting to do ...

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna: If you modify the above script (or write one from scratch) you can post the result code as an answer yourself (and accept that), so others can benefit too :)

Comment: @n8wrl: `NULL` is a placeholder for missing data. No more and no less. Whether it means "we don't know whether this person has a middle name" or "person is known to have no middle name" or "person is known to have a middle name but we have no means of knowing it" or "person is known to have a middle name and they are letting us know what it is tomorrow" or any other variation on the theme are semantics only further information about the data model in question can reveal.

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna: substituting one magic missing data value (`NULL`) with another (empty string) to suit your front end code sounds like going from one disaster to another. There are better ways of handling missing data. As you are already prepared to take on a redesign I suggest you take the opportunity of making a truly drastic step and disallow `NULL` and empty string throughout your data model :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you can build dynamic SQL statement:

```
  declare @sSQl nvarchar(max)=''
SELECT  
@sSQl=@sSQl+'UPDATE ['+TABLE_NAME+ '] SET ['+COLUMN_NAME+']='''''+' WHERE ['+COLUMN_NAME+ '] IS NULL'+CHAR(13)
 FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE DATA_TYPE LIKE '%CHAR%'

exec sp_executesql @ssql
```

Answer (score 3):

Personally I think it's a bad idea to replace `null` with empty string.

But you asked for it, so here it is

```
UPDATE table1 SET field1 = '' WHERE field1 IS NULL
```

The other option is to solve it in your select statements:

```
SELECT coalesce(field1, '') as field1_excl_nulls FROM table1
```

This will replace `null` in the output with empty strings, whilst still leaving the null inside the database.

Comment: I thought that was the answer too, but the OP is trying to generically iterate over all the columns.

Comment: ... over all columns over all tables in the db.

Comment: @All I'm talking about things that don't need to be null and really its is just a matter of preference to be consistent, re my clauses going to be where field = '' or field is null ... I'm not talking about PK of FK's these are all int not null identity fields.  @kirk Woll yes iteration like rebuilding all indexing with sp_MSforeachtable @command1="print '?' DBCC DBREINDEX ('?')"

Comment: That is my exact point !!! I don't want to coalesce every query in my application in instances where it is wholly unnecessary lol ...

Comment: @Bumble I get that, I'd know how to do it in MySQL, but for MSSQL someone else will need to help you out.