# Getting type of column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, types

For example I want to do something like this :

```
//if the Column type is nvarchar
//do something

//if the Column type is int
//do something
```

**EDITED:**

for example :

i have a table with columns(col1 is int,col2 is nvarchar),and i have data in this table,for example

```
col1 : 1,2,3,4,NULL and col2 : a,b,d,f,E,NULL
```

now i want to fill NULL data of col1 with 0 and NULL data of col2 with " "

Comment: A column in a table? A parameter? ...? What is the context of your IF statement, and what is "do something"? Why don't you know the data types of your columns?

Comment: yes a column of table,i want to do:if for example the column type is int, i declare an int variable

Comment: But how are you specifying the column name? Is this a column name that is passed in as a parameter? Just trying to understand the context and what you're trying to do. As stated, the question makes little sense to me.

Comment: the column name and type is specified in design mode of table in SSMS,yes its an input parameter

Comment: As I've stated in my answer, I think if you want better help you'll need to tell us what you're actually trying to do, not asking how to branch depending on column type. This is going to lead to more questions, not answers.

Comment: I Got My Best Answer Here : 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335951/replace-null-varchar-feilds-with-empty-string-for-whole-db][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335951/replace-null-varchar-feilds-with-empty-string-for-whole-db

Comment: @AaronBertrand:sorry sir

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you know the table and the column name, then:

```
DECLARE @tn sysname;

SELECT @tn = TYPE_NAME(system_type_id) 
FROM sys.columns 
WHERE name = @column_name 
AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.tablename');

IF @tn = N'nvarchar'
     DECLARE @x nvarchar(32);

IF @tn = N'int'
     DECLARE @i int;
```

However note that you won't be able to declare the *same* variable name with different data types this way, even if SQL Server will only ever reach one of them. You will get something like:

> Msg 134, Level 15, State 1
> The variable name '@i' has already
> been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or
> stored procedure.

If you know the name of the table then you can build a dynamic SQL statement like you propose as follows (note that this only covers a subset of types - but should give you the idea):

```
DECLARE @table nvarchar(512) = N'dbo.whatever';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT ';

SELECT @sql = @sql 
    + STUFF((SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + N' = COALESCE(' 
    + QUOTENAME(c.name) + N',' + CASE
      WHEN t.name LIKE N'%int' THEN N'0'
      WHEN t.name LIKE N'%char' THEN N''' '''
      END + N')'
 FROM sys.types AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c 
ON t.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
AND t.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
WHERE c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@table)
ORDER BY c.column_id
FOR XML PATH(''), 
TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, N'');

SET @sql = @sql + N' FROM ' + @table;
--SET @sql = @sql + N' WHERE...'

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

I don't know how you could even dream of doing this without dynamic SQL. And ugh, that's a lot of work to prevent your presentation tier from having to deal with NULLs. That is probably the better place to deal with this.

Comment: thanks,i want to fill null cells of data(foreach table),if the type of column is int ,fill null cell with 0,and if its nvarchar,fill it by " "

Comment: "Fill null cells" ... are we still talking about SQL Server here?

Comment: for example i have a table with columns(col1 in int,col2 in nvarchar),and i have data in this table,for example col1 have 1,2,3,4,NULL and col2 have a,b,d,f,NULL,now i want to fill NULL data of col1 with 0 and NULL data of col2 with " ",thanks

Comment: @arash please state your actual requirements in your question. Word problems with pseudo code in a comment are not going to receive very much attention from me.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you were looking for?

```
declare @columns as table
(col1 int,col2 nvarchar)

insert @columns
values (1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'d'),(4,'f'),(null,null)

select isnull(col1,0), isnull(col2,'') from @columns
```

Comment: Except the table name is passed in, so he doesn't know what columns will be in the query or what data types they are.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  typ.name, c_name,CASE when system_type_id <> 243  then typ.max_length 
                              when system_type_id = 243 then   c_maxlen
                         END AS [Maxlen1] ,
                         CASE when system_type_id <> 243  then typ.precision 
                              when system_type_id = 243 then   c_precision
                         END AS [precision] ,

                         CASE when system_type_id <> 243  then typ.scale 
                              when system_type_id = 243 then   c_scale
                         END AS [scale] ,

                         CASE when system_type_id <> 243  then typ.is_nullable 
                              when system_type_id = 243 then   c_nullability
                         END AS [nullabilty] ,
                         CASE 
                         WHEN system_type_id = 34    THEN 'image'
             WHEN (system_type_id = 35 OR cid = 35)    THEN 'text'
             WHEN (system_type_id = 36  OR cid = 36)  THEN 'uniqueidentifier'
             WHEN (system_type_id = 40  OR cid = 40)  THEN 'date'
             WHEN (system_type_id = 41  OR cid = 41)  THEN 'time'
             WHEN (system_type_id = 42  OR cid = 42)  THEN 'datetime2'
             WHEN (system_type_id = 48  OR cid = 48)  THEN 'tinyint'
             WHEN (system_type_id = 52  OR cid = 52)  THEN 'smallint'
             WHEN (system_type_id = 56  OR cid = 56)  THEN 'int'
             WHEN (system_type_id = 58  OR cid = 58)  THEN 'smalldatetime'
             WHEN (system_type_id = 59  OR cid = 59)  THEN 'real'
             WHEN (system_type_id = 60  OR cid = 60)  THEN 'money'
             WHEN (system_type_id = 61  OR cid = 61)  THEN 'datetime'
             WHEN (system_type_id = 62  OR cid = 62)  THEN 'float'
             WHEN (system_type_id = 98  OR cid = 98)  THEN 'sql_variant'
             WHEN (system_type_id = 99  OR cid = 99)  THEN 'ntext'
             WHEN (system_type_id = 104 OR cid = 104)   THEN 'bit'
             WHEN (system_type_id = 106 OR cid = 106)  THEN 'decimal'
             WHEN (system_type_id = 108 OR cid = 108)  THEN 'numeric'
             WHEN (system_type_id = 122 OR cid = 122)  THEN 'smallmoney'
             WHEN (system_type_id = 127 OR cid = 127)  THEN 'bigint'
             WHEN (system_type_id = 165 OR cid = 165)  THEN 'varbinary'
             WHEN (system_type_id = 167 OR cid = 167)  THEN 'varchar'
             WHEN (system_type_id = 173 OR cid = 173)  THEN 'binary'
             WHEN (system_type_id = 175 OR cid = 175)  THEN 'char'
             WHEN (system_type_id = 189 OR cid = 189)  THEN 'timestamp'
             WHEN (system_type_id = 231 OR cid = 231)  THEN 'nvarchar'
             WHEN (system_type_id = 239 OR cid = 239)  THEN 'nchar'
             WHEN (system_type_id = 241 OR cid = 241)  THEN 'xml'
--             when (system_type_id = 243 OR cid = 243)  THEN 'TABLE'
         END AS [Type]
  FROM sys.types as typ  left outer join (select table_types.name tt_name, columns.name c_name ,columns.max_length c_maxlen ,columns.precision c_precision ,columns.scale c_scale,columns.is_nullable c_nullability ,columns.system_type_id cid
                                          from sys.table_types , sys.columns  
                                          where columns.object_id = table_types.type_table_object_id)  tt
 on  (typ.name = tt.tt_name)                           
 where typ.is_user_defined = 1
```